# Get post ID from a link

Tags: posts, custom-field

I will try to explain my issue as good as i can. Please take a look at the following page in my [website.](http://staging.besmart.com.cy/offers/supermarkets/sample-offers/)

We have:

- The main page
- Inside the main page there is a "view offer" button
- The "view offer" button links to a post.
- The post has an expiration date (done through a plugin)
- Underneath the "view offer" button there is a "valid until" field

What i am trying to achieve is the following:

I would like to get the post ID behind the link automatically, use the post ID to get the post's expiration date and then display it next to the "valid until" field automatically. I can already achieve this but i would like to be a bit more automated. Here's the code i am using so far:

```
<?php 
$postid = 4407;
$date_format = __( 'd / m / Y' );
$expiration_date = get_post_meta( $postid, '_expiration_date', true);
if (get_post_status($postid)=='publish')
echo date_i18n( $date_format, strtotime( $expiration_date ) ); 
?>
```

My problem with the above code is that it's only valid if i already know the Post ID number and since i have many pages and posts, i would have to create different code for each page and post. I would like to create a single code that could apply to all of my pages. So basically, i would like to grab the post ID automatically based on the link behind the "view offer" button.

As for how i am using PHP, i have a plugin that allows me to create PHP code snippets and then use them anywhere i like as shortcodes. Therefore, i have a shortcode with the PHP code above next to "valid until" field.

I'm not sure that is possible or if my approach to begin with is wrong but any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Charis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're not after the current post/page ID, but rather trying to find the ID for some url from your site.

Then you should try out the handy [`url_to_postid()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid) WordPress core function.

It returns the post/page ID if it exists, else `0`.

**Example:**

```
echo url_to_postid( 'http://example.com/2014/11/14/hello-world' );

// Outputs the post ID as 1 in this example.
```

**Update:**

*Reply to the comments:* You could create a custom field, called e.g. `url_offer`, from the backend

[image: Example for a custom field]

and use:

```
$url_offer = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , 'url_offer', true );
```

to retrieve it on the front end.

Comment: Thinking about it, you actually might have understood the question correctly here. I was not really sure, so I posted my understanding as a comment :-). Can see the Friday feeling has already kicked in.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies! Yes, birgire is correct on what i'm trying to achieve. url_to_postid() seems useful but again, i would have to state the URL to the post. I am trying to get that automatically without needing to input any information like Post ID or URL

Comment: I am running an offers website with lots of pages and posts. If it helps, each page will always be related to a specific post.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Let's see what happens, wouldn't be the first time I misunderstood things ;-) ps: here's a [suggestion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wa2nLEhUcZ0https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_BszJzLyxI) for the song of the day, some Friday feeling ;-)

Comment: @thundertrax ok great, you could for example store the url or post id in a custom field?

Comment: I will surely second that. Big 'The Cure' fan me. :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen hehe, meant to have posted this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_BszJzLyxI) ;-)

Comment: @birgire thumbs up for your song suggestion!

Comment: Ok, so just to understand the idea, could i perhaps get the Post ID from inside the post, store it to a custom field and then use on my code above?

Comment: Also second the new suggestion, lol. Mistakes are blamed on Friday

Comment: I would appreciate if you bare with me here cause my PHP knowledge is at beginner level, this means that i would have to create a custom field for each post right?

Comment: yes that's the idea

Comment: Well the idea was to not create a different set of code for each post but i guess i won't be able to avoid that after all :) nonetheless let me thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe we are misunderstanding each other here ;-) You  use the same code for all posts, but I meant you just have to add the different "offer" url to each post via custom field from the wp-admin backend. Sorry if this wasn't clear. I updated the answer with a screenshot.

Comment: Yes now i understand what you mean - much more useful! Thanks again for the help, really useful information :)

Comment: @birgire ignore my previous reply, your solution worked as a charm! Regards, Charis

Comment: ok no problem, glad to hear it worked for you ;-)